# Is there any wallet that allows safely storing private keys in an offline computer?

Tags: wallet, security, private-key

I have a computer that is 100% disconnected from the internet. I'd like to:

1. Generate my own private keys by dice rolls;
2. Import them on the offline computer wallet;
3. Send coins to their addresses;
4. Spend those coins by signing the transaction offline and sending to the network from another connected computer, i.e., the online computer never has access to the private keys.

Is there any Bitcoin wallet that allows this use case?

Answer (score 1):

Armory will allow you to do everything except #1. That, you can do with a livecd:

http://www.swansontec.com/bitcoin-dice.html

Comment: I'm reading about it, looks awesome, thanks. But why no dice wallets? It seems so worried about safety, yet ignores the fact RNG isn't trustable?

Comment: I actually had an Armory plugin coded up that would generate a new wallet based on a shuffled deck of cards. Maybe I'll release that so this can be done. FYI, a deck of cards can produce a lot more entropy faster than dice rolls.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the use of bitaddress.org and coinb.in.  You can download both sites locally, or clone from github and put them on a thumb drive. Use bitaddress to convert your dice rolls to WIF using the 'wallet details' tab, and then you can use coinb.in to sign the transaction offline when you are ready to spend.